# Uncountable open cover of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

The question posed to me is to find an uncountable open subcover of $\mathbb{R}$ such that it has no finite subcover, but I can't even think of a way to define an uncountable open cover.

Comment: How many intervals of the form $(a-1,a+1)$ are there?

Comment: What about $(x-1,x+1)$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Good lord. That's so simple I couldn't even think of it... Ha thanks to both!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the collection $\{(a,b)\mid a<b\in\Bbb R\}$, the collection of non-trivial finite length intervals.

Note that while there is no finite subcover, there is always a countable subcover. Spaces with this property, $\Bbb R$ included, are known as Lindelof spaces.

Answer (score 1):

$$~~~~~\{(-r,r):r\in\mathbb{R}\}~~~~$$

Answer (score 1):

Just take a cover by sets of the form $U_{\alpha} = (\alpha-1, \alpha + 1)$ for each $\alpha \in \mathbb R$. This cover is visibly uncountable because I just put it in bijection with $\mathbb R$ itself. This visibly has no finite subcover.

You can also get countable covers of $\mathbb R$ with no finite subcover, for example consider vadim123's example with $r \in \mathbb N$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $(a-1,a+1)$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$. How many are there? Can you think of an open cover built with these sets? Does it have a finite subcover?